# Firestore security rules not working on specific field

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Rules:

```
match /transactions/{transaction} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
}
```

Database:

[image]

ts file:

```
 this.transCollection = afs.collection<Transaction>('transactions',ref => ref.where('cust_id', '==', this.cust_id).orderBy('created','desc'));
     this.transactions = this.transCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map(actions => actions.map(a => {
         const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Transaction;

         const id = a.payload.doc.id;
         return { id, data };
       }))
     );
```

Error:
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Please update your question to include the minimal code with which you can trigger this error.

Comment: Code is working fine without security rules @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2):

Security rules don't filter data by themselves. The security rules instead only allow queries that are guaranteed to will only ever match documents that are allowed. If there is a chance that a query returns documents that are not allowed, the security rules reject the query straight away.

Your query filters on `cust_id` while the rules allow/disallow on `user_id`. This means your query is trying to retrieve documents you don't have access to. Since your query might return a document with the wrong `user_id`, the rules reject the query. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

My best guess is that you want your rules to match on `cust_id` too:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.cust_id;
```

With these rules, they match the condition of the query, so the read/listener will be allowed.

Comment: No cust_id is a different from uid, i need data filter with cust_id but also need to check user_id match with current user id so user can only access his customers.

Comment: But the user can pass in whatever value they want for `cust_id` then, can't they? So there's nothing for the security rules to enforce in that case, it's just a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, nothing wrong with condition but before uid with field based condition need to allow requests from authenticated users and then read if user_id is match with current uid:

```
// Allow a read if request user id is same as resourse user_id
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
```

Rules:

```
match /transactions/{transaction} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
}
```

ts file:

```
//Add user_id in where condition 
this.transCollection = afs.collection<Transaction>('transactions',ref => ref.where('user_id', '==', this.user_id).where('cust_id', '==', this.cust_id).orderBy('created','desc'));
     this.transactions = this.transCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map(actions => actions.map(a => {
         const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Transaction;

         const id = a.payload.doc.id;
         return { id, data };
       }))
     );
```